# select different record with same value

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

> Tablename= User field: username, taxCode,firstName, lastName.

I want to select all the Users that have the same taxCode, but different username. I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
select *
from User where (select COUNT(u.taxCode)
from User u
where u.taxCode=u.taxCode)>1
;
```

Comment: u.taxCode=u.taxCode ? are you sure ?

Comment: Keep trying. It will be From User u1 Inner Join User u2 On u1.taxCode=U2.taxCode then I am sure you can figure out the Where from that.

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan, i'm not sure of u.taxCode=u.taxCode, but what i want is to search the same taxcode.

Comment: @LizLamperouge, dint the inner join also work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause. This should do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM User u GROUP BY u.taxCode HAVING COUNT(u.taxCode) > 1
```

Comment: with the query that you have wrote, what is the result? is the only record that have the same taxcode, right?

Comment: It works because `GROUP BY` puts all records with the same tax code together but `COUNT` separates it again to only records that have the same tax code more than once